# Accessing window server 2012 (not R2) storage space from windows 10

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

As per title.

I have an old computer with 4 disks that make up a storage pool from windows server 2012 (non R2).

Can I attach those 4 disks to the windows 10 machine and load them up on windows 10? Or do I have to stick to Windows server? Do I have to upgrade them through 2016

Comment: Yes; Windows Server 2012 can be used as a file storage server with Windows 10.  Will Windows Server 2016 have better features, sure, but I assume you don’t have a license to that edition otherwise you would be using it.

Comment: I meant attaching the disks directly in the windows 10 machine, not via a file server. @Ramhound